# Specifying navigation buttons

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, navigation

I am making a Navigation based application and i've noticed a flaw in my app. Even though i have multiple buttons, each having its own title the button leads you to the same screen no matter what button i press. Is there a way to make sure that each button leads to a page specific to the button pressed. Such as clicking Options and it bringing you to the option menu not clicking images and it bringing you to the options menu. Any help would be appreciated Thank you.
This is my stack popping method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Anotherviewcontroller *detailViewController = [[Anotherviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Anotherviewcontroller" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.currentItem = @"Years";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];

}
```

Comment: Please post the code that is in the "- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {" section of the ViewController code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the indexPath to determine which button/cell has been selected and then, maybe with a switch statement if there are alot, create the the appropriate controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      if(indexPath.row == 0) {
         Anotherviewcontroller *detailViewController = [[Anotherviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Anotherviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
         detailViewController.currentItem = @"Years";
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
         [detailViewController release];

      } else {
         MessageViewController *messageViewController = [[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Messageviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:messageViewController animated:YES];
         [messageViewController release];
      }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful but i have a roster type set up. Where i have Names>Years>PDFNameList>PDF Document....And i want each name to lead to its specific set of yeas and PDF titles....does this mean i have to create view Controller for each name?

Comment: No, you have to change your controller to work with your input: year and pdf and so on. Then, all you have to do is figure out which year/pdf has been selected by the current indexPath. Write a method something like: `- (MyData *)dataForIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)anIndexPath...` which you call in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and pass your data to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set indexPath.row as a tag of each btn when you are creating cells and then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can check for that tag.

Comment: If i am right then you have these buttons in cells. and you can call setTag function to these btns and a common target to all btn and in that target function you can check for the button tag.